# .net framework windows application Azure dev ops build does not create .EXE

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines

I am working on .net framework 4.7.2, tried to integrated the azure devops build pipeline. below shows the YML used
# .NET Desktop

```
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- Development

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x86'
  buildConfiguration: 'debug'
  

steps:

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/t:restore'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/t:publish /p:PublishSingleFile=True /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x86 /p:outputpath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\'
```

It does not create EXE file. Can somebody let me know what's wrong here? If I remove the restore it gives missing reference errors

Comment: Hi, Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, restore steps must contain otherwise the required packages will not be downloaded.

I think you need build step, below YAML works on my side:

```
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

[image]

Comment: yeah, i could fix the issue with the help of the yaml provided